# Create a directory to store output mask, for image segmentation task

Tags: python, image-processing, file-upload, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

following the tutorial [Kaggle Notebook for Unet](https://www.kaggle.com/code/dikshabhati2002/image-segmentation-u-net/notebook), I am trying to create a function that could store the predicted mask in a folder. While trying below codes, I am getting error *'built-in function imread returned NULL without setting an error'* [image]

Please suggest a modification or redirect for potential solutions.

```
import cv2
import os

image_dir = "/content/sample_data/Output"

def pred_images(sample_image, sample_mask, path):
    pred_mask = model.predict(sample_image[tf.newaxis, ...])
    print(pred_mask.shape)
    pred_mask = pred_mask.reshape(img_size[0],img_size[1],1)
    img= cv2.imread(pred_mask, 1)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, '*.png'), img)

for i in range(len(train_dataset)):
  for image, mask in TRAIN.take(i):
    sample_image, sample_mask= image, mask
    pred_images(sample_image, sample_mask, {image_dir})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code:

1. You are using [`imread`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imread-method/) for what exactly? [`cv2.imread`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imread-method/) ismeant to open an image *file* and read the image into a variable. That is, to "convert" a *string* with filename into a *matrix* with the actual pixel values.
   However, you are applying `imread` to a matrix `mask_pred` -- what are you doing there? This makes no sense, thus the error message you got.
2. You are trying to **write** your image, `img` to a file name `'/content/sample_data/Output/*.png'` -- this is NOT a valid file name. You are not allowed to use `'*'` (and a few [other special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060/1714410)) in file names.
3. Moreover, your `path` argument is set to `{image_dir}` -- that is, you are making a [set](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp) with one element (`image_dir`) and then try and use this **set** as the `path` for the file.